# How to display data on a scroll in a Report Services report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am building a recipe book report (SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2) for client and they want the ingredients to look like they are on a [scroll](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/215665/215665,1217602499,1/stock-photo-blank-scroll-manuscript-15602548.jpg). But the scroll needs to adjust in length as different recipes have more or less ingredients.

The "ingredient scroll" will just be a part of the recipe book report (sitting in the top right corner). The rest of the page will have other lists and photographs of the steps.

If this is not possible, then I'm looking something that will create the same effect and look impressive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might take some graphics editing....

Take a scroll image and cut off the top part. Put that graphic as the heading on the page.  Then put the bottom part of the image as a footer. Then for the body background, use an image that looks like the middle of the page.

So, the top scroll image and bottom scroll image become heading & footing and the body will dynamically expand based on how much data you have.